# New MQL5 calendar functions - no values?

Tags: mql, mql5

I can't seem to get any economic event values with MQL5's new calendar functions (see https://www.metatrader5.com/en/releasenotes).

Specifically...

```
MqlCalendarValue value[9999999];

ulong changeID=33212160;


int OnInit()

  {

   CalendarValueLastByEvent(840040003,changeID,value);

   ArrayPrint(value);

   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);

  }
```

...does work but it only returns 0-values for datetime 1970 01 01.

Any solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was on MetaQuotes' side and they fixed it with a new MetaTrader build realease. My above code now works. Thanks, MetaQuotes!

Answer (score 0):

You are printing an array of 10,000,000 values. For sure you will not find what you want.

```html
MqlCalendarValue value[];  // No need to oversize a static array, let it be dynamic

ulong eventID=840040003;   // Bad idea to hardcode ID this way, but let's keep it for demonstration purpose.
ulong changeID=33212160;
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Script program start function                                    |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnStart()
  {
//---
   CalendarValueLastByEvent(840040003,changeID,value);

   for(int i=0;i<ArraySize(value);i++)
     {
      if(value[i].event_id==840040003)
        {
         //--- print only the required value
         ArrayPrint(value,_Digits,NULL,i,1);
         break;
        }
     }
  }
```

Results :

[Experts log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJf5s.png)